# How to explain the end of the game from the point of view of the kids?

Tags: plot-explanation, jumanji

In *Jumanji* (1995) Robin Williams' character is sucked into a board game as a kid in 1969, while his friend Sarah escapes. He lives in the game-world jungle for 26 years until two different kids bring him back in the overworld by rolling the die and continuing the first turn. They unleash all sorts of jungle monstrosities and the only way to send them all back is to finish the game. In the end Robin Williams wins the game and he and his girlfriend are sent back to 1969 and are able to live a normal life. 26 years later, they reunite with the two kids at a Christmas party, who are now the same age as they were during the game. They recognize them, but the kids don't recognize them back because from their point of view they have never met.

How did that situation feel like from the point of view of the kids? Not the ones at the Christmas party but the ones that were there when the game ended. Did they cease to exist, Thanos-style? Did they get sent back in time to before they even existed? They'd eventually be born again, but it wouldn't be *them*, it would be different kids with identical genes. Did they get left behind in a different timeline? In which case, there is a timeline in which Robin Williams' character and Sarah would remain dead/non-existent.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but do we know whether kids did not recognize Alan & Sarah. I always assumed kids did recognize them, and I was confused about the process, did they always have the memories and knowledge of that alternate timeline from their inception?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a plot hole in Jumanji.

Because in [Jumanji: Welcome to the Jungle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumanji:_Welcome_to_the_Jungle), everybody returns to their original timeline and remembers all the events.

Spencer, Anthony, Bethany and Martha were teenagers when they got sucked into the game. Alex got sucked into game 20 years before them.

But at the end of game everybody returns to their timeline and are reunited in current time i.e 2017 where Spencer, Anthony, Bethany and Martha are still teenagers but Alex has grown up into his 40's.

If this was to be true about Jumanji (1995), Peter and Judy should be able to recognize Alan and Sarah in Alan and Sarah's current timeline.

Comment: That memory part is answered by the director, refer to my answer on sister site https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/241113/6006

Comment: Thank you for pointing to this answer. I see your point. So the question remains as to what Alex did differently that game still landed in Spencer's hands.

Comment: The plot hole you point at isn't quite there. The party at the end of Jumanji takes place in the timeline **before** Peter and Judy's parents go on a skiing trip. But Peter and Judy only joined the game _after_ their parents' deaths on said skiing trip. Therefore, the post-game Peter and Judy's conciousness jumps back into time, but lands "after" the party that Alan/Sarah invite them to. The plot hole would only be proven if Judy and Peter **never** remember. But the movie leaves it open that they (in the near future) will suddenly remember at the time post-game Peter and Judy jump back to.

Comment: My point is Alan/Sarah avoided Ski trip and altered the future. But it's unclear how Alex might have altered or even if he did so game still landed in school's basement for Spencer to find it.

Comment: @Rahul Maybe Alex just never impacted the others' lives in the time between his return and meeting the others. This could be because he was afraid of a time paradox (as a precaution) or because he just didn't do anything relevant.

Comment: I'm not sure it's fair to permit a sequel to retroactively create a plot hole in the previous film, since sequels are often created by different people whose commitment to preserving the integrity of the first chapter usually takes a backseat to making the second one financially viable. Hollywood typically takes itself to be in the business of creating sellable products, not cultivating internally consistent worlds.

Comment: Isn't Jumanji: Welcome To The Jungle actually a computer game version of Jumanji? That being the case it's not a plot hole if the two are different. Assuming it was created after the board game, the developers might have reckoned that it would be better if all parties could remember the experience, and so added it as a feature.

Comment: @komodosp: The game developed itself into computer version from board game. So there is no human developer involved. It's supernatural element.

Answer (score -2):

The concept of time travel in most Sci-Fi works as such: at any given point in time decisions can be made that send the current timeline into distinct directions.  Think of it like a tree branch, with each decision being an offshoot.

In the Peter and Judy's timeline, they probably parted ways, went on to live awesome lives and maybe even kept in touch with Alan and Sarah.

In Alan and Sarah's timeline, they had experienced the event that brought them back to 1969, and lived their lives forward, knowing Peter and Judy's parents would be killed in a skiing accident.  Almost like a premonition, because Peter and Judy were a long ways away from even being born.  They were able to divert that timeline allowing the parents to live, and recognized the kids at the party.

In that timeline, Alan and Sarah were complete strangers to Peter and Judy.  They had never met them before, because they were born long after 1969.